# Get `Error::source` from a generic that might be either `std::error::Error`, `Box<dyn Error>` or `anyhow::Error`

Tags: rust

I'm working on a graceful shutdown library for tokio, and part of that is error handling.

I give the user the choice for which type is used for error wrapping, which is here called `WrapperType`. Then, he can pass any error through it that implements `Into<WrapperType>` into the library.

`WrapperType` of course has to be some kind of Error itself. My current use cases are limited to `WrapperType` being one of `T: std::error::Error`, `Box<dyn Error>`, `anyhow::Error` and `miette::Error`.

Now here comes the problem: When an error gets passed through my library, I want to retrieve its description (no problem) and its source (that's where the problem comes in).

I simplified the code of the library to the following minimal example:

```rust
use std::error::Error;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct WrappedError<WrapperType: ToString>(WrapperType);

fn wrap<WrapperType, ErrType>(err: ErrType) -> WrappedError<WrapperType>
where
    ErrType: Into<WrapperType>,
    WrapperType: ToString,
{
    WrappedError(err.into())
}

impl<T: ToString> WrappedError<T> {
    fn get_description(&self) -> String {
        self.0.to_string()
    }
    fn get_source(&self) -> Option<&(dyn Error + 'static)> {
        /* this is the problem */
        todo!();
    }
}

// This is just a dummy error type to demonstrate errors with
// and without a source
#[derive(thiserror::Error, Debug, miette::Diagnostic)]
enum MyError {
    #[error("An error")]
    AnError,
    #[error("An indirect error")]
    Indirect(#[source] Box<dyn Error + Send + Sync>),
}

fn main() {
    wrap::<MyError, _>(MyError::AnError);
    wrap::<MyError, _>(MyError::Indirect("Real error.".into()));

    wrap::<anyhow::Error, _>(MyError::AnError);
    wrap::<anyhow::Error, _>(MyError::Indirect("Real error.".into()));
    wrap::<anyhow::Error, _>(anyhow::anyhow!("Anyhow error."));

    wrap::<miette::Error, _>(MyError::AnError);
    wrap::<miette::Error, _>(MyError::Indirect("Real error.".into()));
    wrap::<miette::Error, _>(miette::miette!("Miette error."));

    wrap::<Box<dyn Error>, _>(MyError::AnError);
    wrap::<Box<dyn Error>, _>(MyError::Indirect("Real error.".into()));
    wrap::<Box<dyn Error>, _>(anyhow::anyhow!("Anyhow error."));
    wrap::<Box<dyn Error>, _>(miette::miette!("Miette error."));

    // All of those are errors of some kind.
    // I'd like to retrieve a textual description and the error source from them
    // through the WrappedError.
    let err: WrappedError<MyError> = wrap(MyError::Indirect("Real error.".into()));
    println!("Description: {}", err.get_description());
    println!("Source: {:?}", err.get_source());
}
```

---

Now there's a couple of things I've tried, but most of them run into one of those problems:

- Rust does not yet have generic specialization
- `anyhow::Error`, `miette::Error` and `Box<dyn Error>` do not implement `std::error::Error`
- You cannot specialize an impl for `Box<dyn Error>` and `T where T: std::error::Error` at the same time, because the compiler says `Box<dyn Error>` might one day implement `std::error:Error`, even though that will never be the case
- It's impossible to create an `impl` block for types that have *either* `std::error:Error` or `Deref<Target = std::error::Error>`

The textual description, on the other hand, works without a problem, because all four types implement `ToString` and therefore `WrapperType: ToString` is possible.

However, getting the source is a problem, because the four types require different methods to do that.
On the surface, they look identically:

```rust
let e: MyError = MyError::AnError;
e.source();
let e: anyhow::Error = MyError::AnError.into();
e.source();
let e: miette::Error = MyError::AnError.into();
e.source();
let e: Box<dyn Error> = MyError::AnError.into();
e.source();
```

Under the hood, they are actually different:

```rust
let e: MyError = MyError::AnError;
std::error::Error::source(&e);

let e: anyhow::Error = MyError::AnError.into();
std::error::Error::source(&*e);

let e: miette::Error = MyError::AnError.into();
std::error::Error::source(&*e);

let e: Box<dyn Error> = MyError::AnError.into();
std::error::Error::source(&*e);
```

Meaning, the other error types only work because they implement `Deref<Target = dyn Error>`.
Sadly, it's impossible to say that `WrapperType` should be **either** `Deref<Target = dyn Error>` or `std::error::Error`.

I tried implementing a trait to solve the issue, but sadly, `Deref<Target = dyn Error>` and `std::error::Error` collide:

```rust
trait GetSource {
    fn get_source_internal(&self) -> Option<&(dyn Error + 'static)>;
}

impl<T: ToString> GetSource for WrappedError<T>
where
    T: Deref<Target = dyn Error + Send + Sync + 'static>,
{
    fn get_source_internal(&self) -> Option<&(dyn Error + 'static)> {
        (&*self.0).source()
    }
}

impl<T: ToString> GetSource for WrappedError<T>
where
    T: std::error::Error,
{
    fn get_source_internal(&self) -> Option<&(dyn Error + 'static)> {
        self.0.source()
    }
}
```

```
conflicting implementations of trait `GetSource` for type `WrappedError<_>`
```

So I'm officially out of ideas on how to achieve this.
Any help is welcome.

Comment: IIRC, anyhow is a crate that is though to be used in a binary, not in libraries (for the reasons you have found). Its library "counterpart" would be [thiserror](https://crates.io/crates/thiserror).

Comment: The problem is that my library *forwards* errors from the user to the user. therefore I can't say "please use only thiserror based errors" because that would make the library pointless. If a user wants to use `anyhow` as an error wrapper, he shouldn't be limited by my library to do so.

Comment: More detailed: The user provides a bunch of callbacks(coroutines) that get called by my library. Then, the errors get collected and passed back to the user.
If the user wants to use anyhow inside of the callbacks, he should be free to do so.

Comment: I have to admit you have confused me a little bit. If you don't want to restrict in any way your user, then you don't even need a wrapper. Just forward the error returned in the callback to the user. If you need that error to adhere to *some* interface, then just *require* it to adhere to that interface.

Comment: Yes that is the exact problem. Which interface? My library passes a collection of errors back to the user. I want this collection itself to implement Error. And I'd like the original errors to be referenced as sources of the error. That requires me to get the original errors as `&dyn Error`. But how do you get `&dyn Error` for a generic that could be `T: Error` or `Box<dyn Error>`?

Comment: If that interface does not already exist, just make one, and ask the users to implement it. For instance, you could have something `trait LibCompatibleError: std::error::Error { ... }`.

Comment: The problem is, it works as-is, and I don't want to change the API. The only feature that is missing is that I keep the connection to the original errors as specified in `source`. So I'd like to retro-fit that to the already published library. But I can't find to way to retrieve the source from all the types specified.

Comment: Further, users want to use `anyhow::Error` as error type, which does not implement `std::error::Error`. I'm fine with hard-coding traits for types, but as soon as I implement a trait for `T: std::error::Error` it **cannot** be implemented for `anyhow::Error` any more, because those two implementations might collide in future.

Comment: Is that the same question as [How to specify generics that can be dereferenced into a trait](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72349304/7884305)? Why did you asked two questions, one of them seems to be less detailed than the other?

Comment: The other one would solve this one, but I made it a separate question because it's inherent a separate question. The question of how to define a type that can be dereferenced into a trait through repeted derefs would be helpful outside of this question.
But it might by an XY problem, because while it would solve my problem here, I'm not sure if that's the correct question I should ask for the problem described here.

Comment: Does the code need to be used in generic context where the error type is unknown, or you can use an inherent method?