# How to specify generics that can be dereferenced into a trait

Tags: rust

I have structs `A` and `B`, where `B` can be dereferenced into `A`.

`A` implements `GetValue` with the function `.get_value()`, and therefore `B` also indirectly implements `GetValue`.

Now I'd like to write a function `print_value` that can accept `&A` and `&B`, so it can internally call `.get_value()` on them. Technically this should be possible, because both of them can be dereferenced into `&GetValue`; `&A` by dereferencing once, and `&B` by dereferencing twice.

The question is: How do I specify the generic of `print_value` to achieve this?

---

Here is my attempt:

```rust
use std::ops::Deref;

//### external library code ######################
struct A(i32);
struct B(A);

impl Deref for B {
    type Target = A;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.0
    }
}

trait GetValue {
    fn get_value(&self) -> i32;
}

impl GetValue for A {
    fn get_value(&self) -> i32 {
        self.0
    }
}

//### my code ####################################
fn print_value<T: Deref>(val: T)
where
    <T as Deref>::Target: GetValue,
{
    println!("{}", val.get_value())
}

fn main() {
    let a = A(1);
    let b = B(A(2));

    println!("{}", a.get_value());
    println!("{}", b.get_value());

    print_value(&a);
    print_value(&b); // < fails with error "the trait bound `B: GetValue` is not satisfied"
}
```

The problem here is that `<T as Deref>::Target: GetValue` does not match `&B`, because `&B` would have to be dereferenced twice. The compiler automatically dereferences many times when a function is called, so is there a way to achieve the same through generics?

---

### Note

I only have power over the implementation of `print_value`. I do not have the power over the other functions.

A more real-life example would be:

- `get_value` = `get_error_source`
- `A` = an error type
- `B` = `Box<dyn A>`
- `GetValue` = `std::error::Error`

I just wanted to keep it as abstract as possible to avoid confusion.
I'm still quite certain that this is not an XY problem.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of making a function have an overly complicated signature just to signify that it can take anything that you know to `get_value` of, you could do a blanket implementation. This way, you automatically signify that something you can `get_value` of, well, you can `get_value` of.

```rust
impl<T> GetValue for T
where
    T: Deref,
    <T as Deref>::Target: GetValue,
{
    fn get_value(&self) -> i32 {
        self.deref().get_value()
    }
}
```

Just adding that makes it work, [see the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ee6be86dbc9c07e193b51601f6b141c3).

Comment: Edited the question to reflect that I don't have power over the other functions

Comment: You say *instead* ... *IS* there a way of creating such an overly complicated signature? I'd even pay money if you could give me such a signature. A signature that matches for everything that can be dereferenced once or twice to get to `GetValue`.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to actually call `deref` on the object, then you would pass a `B` or an `&A` :

```rust
use std::ops::Deref;

...

fn print_value<T: Deref>(val: T)
where
    <T as Deref>::Target: GetValue,
{
    println!("{}", val.deref().get_value())
}

fn main() {
    let a = A(1);
    let b = B(A(2));

    println!("{}", a.get_value());
    println!("{}", b.get_value());

    print_value(&a);
    print_value(b); 
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a3ded78577442b5c40e4d6eaf4f8acc7)

Outputs:

```
1
2
1
2
```

Comment: From the fact that I now got two answers that suggested to change other parts of the code except the actual `print_value` function, I deduce that the actual task of writing such a function cannot be achieved with current state of Rust?

Comment: @Finomnis, I did changed the function, you need to actually call `deref`. Then yes, you also need to adjust some other parts of your code.

Comment: I'm quite certain that calling an object method implies `deref` [already](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=82d4e94421332aa62e589de70636f4b3). 

But thanks, yes, I was afraid that this task is currently not possible without changing code at other places. But at least now I have confirmation.